# Index Ruby on Rails Enums from 1 instead of 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing, enums

Ruby on Rails Enums automatically indexes starting at 0. I'd like to index these starting from 1. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Not clear what you are askng about. Are you asking about indexng in active records? Hoe is enum relevant?

Comment: Enums are assigned in the model using the following syntax

`enum status: ["bored", "busy", "working", "sleeping"]`

It assigns values based on the index in the array.

Turns out you can use an hash instead of an array to assign any enum value you want. Thanks to @trh for this answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is not to use an array at all. Enum is magical. It has the ability to act as a simple array, e.g.

```
enum status: ["bored", "busy", "working", "sleeping"]
```

or a hash, based on how its declared

```
enum status: {bored: 1, busy: 2, working: 3, sleeping: 4}
```

Just make sure in your migration you set a default status, it can be any number you prefer.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I didn't realize you could use a hash. Thanks!